# Adding PPA on Ubuntu Bionic defaults to Eoan Repository

Tags: apt, ppa

I am working on basing a new OS off of Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic, and in order to properly have the OS be recognized as a new distribution, I had to change `/etc/lsb-release`. In order to have it use PPAs, I had to add a file to `/usr/share/python-apt/templates`. This got it to add the PPAs, but, it defaults to Eoan repositories when I attempt to add them.

You can see what I have in [my GitHub repository here.](https://github.com/drauger-os-development/drauger-ppa-enabler)

Is there some other file I need to add? Am I formatting the *.info file wrong? Is it something else?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you changed the `lsb-release` to other, that's what the PPA will pick.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia I left the `Ubuntu_Codename` line in `os-release` set to bionic. Do I need to have this line in `lsb-release` too or should I change something else?

Comment: Not sure but probably yes.  Your noticing the effects.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia I tried adding the `ubuntu_codename` line to lsb-release and got the same results.